# Set drawer items from array list and clicks in MaterialDrawer

Tags: android, sqlite, materialdrawer

in my android application i'm using greeDAO ORM for sqlite. so i retrive my category list :

```
 List<ArticleCategory> categories = articleCategoryDao.queryBuilder().list();
```

each `ArcticleCategory` object has name and description property so i can use these for name and description of drawer items.my question is how to add this list to `myDrawer` items and how to manage their click's event. and this is my drawer codes :

```
    Drawer myDrawer = new DrawerBuilder().withActivity(this).withToolbar(toolbar)
            .addDrawerItems(
                    new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName("Home").withIcon(GoogleMaterial.Icon.gmd_import_contacts).withIconColor(Color.BLACK)
            )
            .withOnDrawerItemClickListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onItemClick(View view, int position, IDrawerItem drawerItem) {

                    return false;
                }
            })
            .withAccountHeader(navigationHeader)
            .withDrawerGravity(GravityCompat.START)
            .build();
```

please keep in my mind i have some static items that i manually and items to drawer and some dynamic that come from database so click event is very important for me in this scenario.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add the `Categories` to the drawer you first have to create the `DrawerItems` you can do this by iterating over your items.

```
ArrayList<IDrawerItem> drawerItems = new ArrayList<>();
for(ArticleCategory category : categories) {
   drawerItems.add(new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(category.getName()).withDescription(category.getDescription()));
   //if you have a id you can also do: .withIdentifier(category.getIdentifier());
   //depending on what you need to identify or to do the logic on click on one of those items you can also set a tag on the item: .withTag(category);
}
```

After you have created your items you add them to your `DrawerBuilder`

```
drawerBuilder.withDrawerItems(drawerItems);
```

Now as the drawer is created you have to write the logic for the `Listener`. Your "static" `DrawerItem`s should define an identifier so you can directly react if one of those is clicked

```
.withOnDrawerItemClickListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onItemClick(View view, int position, IDrawerItem drawerItem) {
      if (drawerItem != null) {
          Intent intent = null;
          if (drawerItem.getIdentifier() == 1) {
              //static item with ID 1
          } else if (drawerItem.getIdentifier() == 2) {
              //static item with ID 2
          } else {
              //if none of your static items were clicked handle the logic for the categories. 
              //now you have the drawerItem which were created from a category
              //you can identify them by identifier, their tag, or name. Depends on what you need to do your logic here

          }
      }

      return false;
  }
})
```